# Rails + ActiveRecord - fighting with "N+1" issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord, has-many

I have these models:

**car:**

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :car_services, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :services, through: :car_services
end
```

**car_service**

```
class CarService < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :service
  validates_uniqueness_of :service_id, scope: :car_id
end
```

**truck**

```
class Truck < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :truck_services, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :services, through: :truck_services
end
```

**truck_service**

```
class TruckService < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :truck
  belongs_to :service
end
```

**service**

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :car_services
  has_many :cars, through: :car_services

  has_many :truck_services
  has_many :trucks, through: :truck_services
end
```

In controllers' actions (there are separated actions for cars and for trucks) I query the models like this:

```
@cars = Car.find_by_sql("SELECT ...")
...
@trucks = Truck.find_by_sql("SELECT ...")
```

and then in the respective views:

```
<% @cars.each do |result| %>
  <li data-services="<% result.services.each do |service| %><%= service.name %>,<% end %>">...</li>
  ...
<% end %>
```

This procedure works very well for `cars`, it's very fast.

Different action for `trucks`, but the same procedure:

```
<% @trucks.each do |result| %>
  <li data-services="<% result.services.each do |service| %><%= service.name %>,<% end %>">...</li>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Now, this procedure is very slow. When I tried to debug why (because as I mentioned, the procedure is same for both models, but for cars it's working very fast even though that in the `car` model is 600k records and in the `truck` "only" 300k), I spotted in the console log following information:

```
...
Service Load (159.1ms)  SELECT `services`.* FROM `services` INNER JOIN `truck_services` ON `services`.`id` = `truck_services`.`service_id` WHERE `truck_services`.`truck_id` = 35769
Service Load (166.8ms)  SELECT `services`.* FROM `services` INNER JOIN `truck_services` ON `services`.`id` = `truck_services`.`service_id` WHERE `truck_services`.`truck_id` = 45681
Service Load (151.4ms)  SELECT `services`.* FROM `services` INNER JOIN `truck_services` ON `services`.`id` = `truck_services`.`service_id` WHERE `truck_services`.`truck_id` = 50974
...
```

How is this possible? Why I don't see these lines also for `cars` and I see them for `truck`? Do I miss something? I was thinking about missing indexes in the MySQL tables, but there aren't used any.

I am fighting with this issue the whole Saturday, but I have no solution for this...

I would be very grateful for an advice how to fix this issue.

Thank you very much guys.

Comment: Do those queries not occur for the car version or are they just faster?

Comment: Is the `SELECT ...` (hidden, yet probably the most relevant piece of code to the question) equivalent for both cars and trucks?

Comment: @FrederickCheung they don't occur and they are faster.

Comment: @numbers1311407 yes, it is. The logic is the same.

Comment: What's `shipper_id` and why it is used in the WHERE clause?

Comment: @katafrakt sorry, a typo - `truck_id`. Fixed in the OP.

Comment: Is there something out of the ordinary happening in the find that requires you to write SQL?  If not the answer is to use the standard solution of eager loading as @OctopusPaul suggests.

Comment: So? Did you get rid of N+1?

Answer (score 1):

I will start with an **advice**: post your sql queries for others to understand exactly what you are doing and to be able to help you

To eliminate N+1 you should use [includes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes) or [preload](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-preload)

In your controllers do this:

```
@cars = Car.includes(:services).all
```

respectively,

```
@trucks = Truck.includes(:services).all
```

You can see that I preferred a much cleaner syntax to find_by_sql.

When you run:

```
@cars = Car.includes(:services).all
```

this will trigger 3 queries:

```
SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars";
SELECT "car_services".* FROM "car_services" WHERE "car_services".car_id IN (?, ?, ? ...);
SELECT "services".* FROM "services" WHERE "services".car_service_id IN (?, ?, ? ...);
```

If you remove N+1 your page will load faster but you should check that all your keys have indexes defined, too.

The above its just an example. You should really post your complete queries for us to understand exactly what you are doing. And those models Car and Truck, they look very similar, maybe it will be a better solution to use [Single Table Inheritance](http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/).

You could rewrite this:

```
<% @trucks.each do |result| %>
  <li data-services="<% result.services.each do |service| %><%= service.name %>,<% end %>">...</li>
<% end %>
```

as this

```
<% @trucks.each do |truck| %>
  <%= content_tag :li, '...', data: {services: truck.services.map(&:name).join(', ')} %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this will help you somehow.